# write the python program for this?

Tags: python

Write a Python program that takes the user's name as input and displays and welcomes them.

Expected behaviour:

Enter your name: Nimal
Welcome Nimal

The Python code for taking the input and displaying the output is already provided.

answer for this code!

Comment: that's not how this site works ;)

Comment: That's not how *learning to program* works…

Comment: Enter your name: `"Nimal Welcome Nimal"`  Output: `"Welcome Nimal Welcome Nimal"` XD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
print("Welcome", name)
```

Comment: Please don't encourage these kinds of zero effort questions by providing an answer to them.